# Which of these is the correct implementation of cosine decay (learning-rate reweighting for neural nets)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras, gradient-descent

I've read the a [Loshchilov & Hutter](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03983.pdf) paper on Stochastic Gradient Descent with Warm Restart (SGDR), and I've found at least one implementation of it for keras ([like this one](https://gist.github.com/jeremyjordan/5a222e04bb78c242f5763ad40626c452#file-sgdr-py)). However, I can imagine two different implementations and want to bounce if off some folks.

As coded [here](https://gist.github.com/jeremyjordan/5a222e04bb78c242f5763ad40626c452#file-sgdr-py), the learning rate decreases with every mini-batch. However, I can imagine a different implementation where it only changes after each epoch. My own intuition says that the latter implementation makes more sense, however it seems most people are coding up the former.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Just for your information, tf.train has implementation for many of these cosine decays:

- [cosine decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/cosine_decay)
- [cosine decay with restarts](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/cosine_decay_restarts)
- [linear cosine decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/linear_cosine_decay)
- [noisy linear cosine decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/noisy_linear_cosine_decay)

Comment: Thank you! That's always great information to know.

Answer (score 1):

Loshchilov & Hutter proposed in their paper to update the learning rate after each batch:

> Within the i-th run, we decay the learning rate with a cosine annealing **for each batch** [...],

as you can see just above Eq. (5), where one run (or cycle) is typically one or several epochs.

Several reasons could motivate this choice, including a **large dataset size**. With a large dataset, one might only run the optimization during few epochs. In this case, updating the learning rate every epoch would only provide few update opportunities. On the other hand, with a small dataset, one can perform more epochs with fewer batches per epoch, and this problem fades away.

From an implementation point of view with Keras, a learning rate update every epoch is slightly more compact thanks to the [LearningRateScheduler callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler). For example, a simple decay can implemented as

```
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler

get_lr = lambda epoch: 0.99 ** epoch
model.fit(..., callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(get_lr)])
```